# How shall we compute the flux in this case?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I have a finite surface charge (in yellow) which cuts a Gaussian surface (in green).

[image]

Red points are the points of singularity on the Gaussian surface (i.e. where $\vec{E}$ is undefined).

Does this singularity (at red points) refrain us from computing flux over the Gaussian surface? Or is there a way to compute the flux? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. The surface has an area of $0$ thus charge $0$, and mathematican's way is to introduce the convention $0\cdot \infty$.

If you really want to think about calculate it in a physical way, use symmetry.

Then it's clear that the flux from each single point at the boundary cancels out.

Comment: Note that fields at the singularity points are not only infinite (this does not create ambiguity) but also points in all direction (this creates ambiguity).

Comment: "Then it's clear that the flux from each single point at the boundary cancels out". How? Please elaborate.

Comment: At the edge, up down canceled, at the "right angle", the cross angle canceled out. The math is different here so don't think about your daily Remiann integeral.

Comment: If $\vec{E}$ is constant, then OK. But what if $\vec{E}$ is varying?

Comment: @faheemahmed400 finite surface, the question is assuming symmetry.

Comment: Why all finite surfaces are symmetric?